# Not Run wince Lazarus TI Cortex-A9

Tags: windows-ce, lazarus, cortex-a

End compilation error message:

```
Error: Illegal parameter: -CpCORTEXM3
```

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty certain Windows CE doesn't support Cortex-M3 anyway...

Comment: ARMV7A instead?

Comment: Used ARMV7A message error: ApCarga.lpr(25,0) Error: Error while assembling exitcode 1

Comment: @Abelisto Test using ARMV7 and FPC 2.6.4 same error.

Comment: [Have you installed the cross-compiler?](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/arm-wince)

Comment: Yes installed and reference in lazarus:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/712800/error.png

Comment: @Abelisto as testing cross-compiler is installed correct computer?

Answer (score 0):

Windows CE requires an MMU, which Cortex-M3 does not have.

Comment: There is no way to compile app for the type of processor TI Cortex-A9 OMAP4430 in Lazarus?

Comment: I am not familiar with the Lazarus environment, so cannot answer that specifically, but Windows CE does run on OMAP CPU's. The issue here seems to be the use of the Cortex M3 option. Cortex A9 and M3 have very different feature sets.

Comment: As an aside, if you are working on Windows CE and unless there's a compelling reason to use Lazarus, you might consider using one of the Microsoft IDE's instead - Platform Builder for OS/OAL work, and Visual Studio for application software.